# Entity Framework 6 generates wrong context code

Tags: c#, entity-framework

At my workplace, we share a project that uses Entity Framework 6.0 for database operations.

In the repository I see modifications in the `MyModel.Context.cs` file (a function was added).

From this using block:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Linq;
```

It was changed to this:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Linq;

[EdmFunction("MyEntities", "DbFunction1")]
public virtual IQueryable<DbFunction1_Result> DbFunction1(Nullable<System.Guid> id)
{
   //some code    
   return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<DbFunction1_Result>("[MyEntities].[DbFunction1](@id)", parameter);
}
```

I updated my working copy and it compiles.

But, whenever I use the `Update model from database`, my code changes back to this:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Linq;
```

We both use EF 6.0 via NuGet.

When I check the EntityFramework dll's properties, I get this:

[image]

What could cause this?

Comment: [Update your EDMX (or rather, the .tt) files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to edit the `.tt` file.
Probably `MyModel.Context.tt` is the template file that generates the MyModel.Context.cs for you, it uses [T4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx) to generate it each time you select `Update model from database` in your `.edmx` file.

Comment: But the T4 file is generated _from the database based on the EF version I use_, doesn't it?

Comment: The .cs is generated from the .tt file, the .tt only uses the parameters you change on the .edmx file. Try to copy and paste your code on this .tt file in the correct place and try to Update model from database, later check if it was generated on the Model.Context.cs.

Comment: Depends also on the version of the Visual Studio you use, please check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613116.aspx on DbContext Generator.

Comment: It seems that the project has mixed EF referencies. It seemingly uses EF 6 _but also contained a `System.Data.Entity` reference_ and the *.tt files were also EF5 compatible, so I delete them, and added a new code generation item as described in the MS guide. Now it gets compiled.